# Is $B_{\ell_1}$ weak-metrizable?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I know that for a Banach space $X$, the unit ball $B_{X}$ is weak metrizable if and only if $X^*$ is separable. My question is that

> Is $B_{\ell_1}$ weak-metrizable?

Comment: $\ell_1^*=\ell_\infty$ but $\ell_\infty$ is not separable

Comment: @Dear Norbert so we can not consider sequence in $B_{\ell_1}$ for wealky convergence?

Comment: Correct. $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 1):

As Norbert said, this is false. When considering sequences, we don't get the accurate picture of weak topology on the unit ball of $\ell^1$: in fact, *we can't even tell it from the norm  topology*.

> *Theorem* (Schur) A sequence  in $\ell^1$ converges weakly if and only if it converges in the norm.

An accessible proof of this theorem is easy to find online: see [this blog post](https://regularize.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/an-elementry-proof-of-schurs-theorem/) or [these notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~nickcook/l1weakstrong.pdf); there is also a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur's_property) (though without a proof).